# Filtering pexpect remote command output

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

I have pexpect to perform a few configs in a remote virtual server.

- I need to run the uptime in this remote server
- get the uptime output
- if the uptime is less than 5min I need to wait otherwise I can move forward and configure this server

  ```
    child = pexpect.spawn(f"virsh console {hostname} --force", timeout=3)
    child.send("\r\r\r")
    child.expect(".*ogin:")

    # Step 1: Log in as root
    print("Step 1: Log in as root")
    self.logger.debug(f"sending USER: {USER}")
    child.sendline(USER)
    child.expect("root.*", timeout=3)
    child.send("\r")
    child.sendline('uptime')
    child.expect("root.*", timeout=3)
    child.send("\r")
    child.expect("root.*", timeout=3)
    r = child.before.decode('utf-8').split("\r")
    print(r)
    child.send("exit")
    child.sendcontrol("]")
  ```

Below is my print(r) output

```
uptime
12:04AM  up  4 mins, 1 user, load averages: 0.87, 0.54, 0.45
```

My problem is sometimes, the child.before don't get the right "uptime" cmd output, so the variable is None and it causes a few issues, once I need to wait a bit until the device is ready to config.

I notice the pexpect buffer is a bit strange and I didn't manage to clear the buffer, to get the child.before when I run the "uptime command"

the child.before is: "Last login: Sat Feb 25 22:57:04 on ttyu0" or "--- Kernel 64-bit"

but never the uptime output.

```
Connected to domain lab_test
Escape character is ^]


FreeBSD/amd64 (Amnesiac) (ttyu0)

login: 

FreeBSD/amd64 (Amnesiac) (ttyu0)

Connected to domain lab_test
Escape character is ^]
amd64

FreeBSD/amd64 (Amnesiac) (ttyu0)

login: root


FreeBSD/amd64 (Amnesiac) (ttyu0)

login: 

FreeBSD/amd64 (Amnesiac) (ttyu0)

login: root
uptime
Last login: Sat Feb 25 22:57:04 on ttyu0

--- Kernel 64-bit
root@:~ # uptime
uptime
10:59PM  up  1:14, 1 user, load averages: 0.63, 0.60, 0.49
```

Comment: what issues are you hitting? what's your question?

Comment: I just edited my question with further info. thanks for any help here

Comment: please post a [repro].